# Xamarin Forms MSAL cache not storing tokens on iOS

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm using the Microsoft.Identity.Client (MSAL) NuGet package to authenticate my users in an Azure B2C directory.  [Just like in this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/azure-ad-b2c/), when my App starts, I call the `AquireTokenSilentAsync()` method to try to authenticate my users, and if it fails, they are sent to the mobile sign-in page.

On Android, this method works so the user only needs to sign in the first time they use the app.  However, on iOS the cached token is never found so the user needs to log in every time they open the app.

Currently, I'm calling `await App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Scopes);` and getting the following error:

```
AcquireTokenSilentHandler.cs: No token matching arguments found in the cache
```

I've also tried calling it using a different overload of the method:

```
await App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, string.Empty,
                               authority, signUpSignInpolicy, false);
```

This method produces the following output in the log:

```
AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition started:
    Authority: (My Authority)
    Scope: (My Client Id)
    ClientId: (My Client Id)
    CacheType: null
```

It then produces the same error as the first one.  I'm assuming part of the issue is that my `CacheType` is null but I'm not sure how to fix this.  Does anyone know what I need to do to make it so my users don't need to sign in every time?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Are you running this on the iOS simulator? When I changed to a physical device it worked fine

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks!